# Name for a special element of a *-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, terminology, c-star-algebras

Let $R$ be a $\ast$-algebra.  Is there a name for an element $x\in R$ that satisfies $x x^{\ast}=0$.

Comment: I was thinking you could call them skew-nilpotent, but that'd be easy to confuse with the skew elements which happen to be nilpotent.

Comment: You tag this with $C^*$-algebras. If $xx^*=0$ in a $C^*$-algebra (or even a pre-$C^*$-algebra), then $x=0$ by the $C^*$-identity. If I would need to come up with a name for an element with this property, I would call such an element "right $*$-absorbing".

Comment: In analogy with inner products maybe it could be called null or isotropoc.

Comment: @rschwieb: It's not just an analogy with inner products. Both names (null and isotropic) are used for vectors satisfying $\langle v, v\rangle=0$ with respect to a bilinear or sesquilinear form (actually, for inner products, there is no such thing). $\langle x,y\rangle=xy^*$ is a sesquilinear form (maybe over commutative rings, I'm not sure what happens if the base ring is non-commutative), so I think this is the best choice.

Comment: @tomasz Of course, I agree!  I've never seen anything useful using a form over a noncommutative ring. I'm a noncommutative algebraist, but forms over noncommutative division rings (even) seemed incredibly uncooperative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an established name, but (as suggested by rschwieb in a comment) it seems natural to call such an element *isotropic* or *null*, since it is such with respect to the natural sesquilinear form given by $\langle x, y\rangle = xy^*$.